# Elixir Phoenix Liveview Component Live Input File Deletes All Other Fields

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I am following this [tutorial](https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/10/12/how-to-do-live-uploads-in-phoenix-liveview.html), in which Ms. DeBenedetto masterfully explains how to do file uploads in a liveview component. I pretty much followed all the instructions, but get strange behavior when selecting the image to be uploaded by

```
<div class="py-5">
   <%= label f, :image %>
   <%= live_file_input @uploads.avatar %>
</div>
```

namely that the other fields get erased and the placeholders are back. So my guess is that the live component gets reloaded, a thing I definetely do not want. The update function is:

```
@impl true
  def update(assigns, socket) do
    {:ok, socket
    |> assign(assigns)
    |> assign(:uploaded_files, [])
    |> allow_upload(:avatar, accept: ~w(.jpg .jpeg), auto_upload: false)}
  end
```

And it definitely has something to do with the form as placing the <%= live_file_input @uploads.avatar %> outside the form does not cause the form fields to be erased when selected.

Is anyone familiar with this situation and does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Is `|> assign(assigns)` indeed needed within this pipe?

Comment: Yes because I need an argument passed to the liveview component as an id tag.

Comment: And Ms. DeBenedetto in https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/10/12/how-to-do-live-uploads-in-phoenix-liveview.html also uses it.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you have mentioned is itself pointing to the official Phoenix doc on upload functionality (https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/uploads.html#content) and I highly recommend checking this out first.

The reason you set the `allow_upload` in your `update` method sets a red light for me. That should be done in `mount` together with the array for uploaded files `assign(:uploaded_files, [])`.

In the before-mentioned doc you have a perfect example of the simplest upload form, just extend it with fields from your changeset (product entity from the tutorial in your case) and you should get all the data together with uploaded files in `def handle_event("save"....)` method.

Comment: If you look at her example, she also uses update. That is because this is not a liveview parent, but one of its components.

Comment: @paulrusu `If you look at her example, she also uses update. ` and if I don't look at it, she doesn't use update?